# Specify a target for less compilation within browser

Tags: javascript, less

I have a page with a short form to input some less values. I then want to take those values and recompile the less (from within the browser, with less.modifyVars(); ), but be able to specify the target file. This is so that I can access it from an iframe from within the page.

Does anyone know how I can specify a target for less compilation in the browser?

Comment: i don't understand what your are asking. less.js reads the less file defined in the document `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />`. You can use `@imports` in this files. Why can't `styles.less` be your target?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with in-browser "less.js" usage so this is quite rough answer.
Basically, no, you can't specify a target for automatic compilation.

#### #1

So you will have to explicitly parse a less file of interest into a string containing the result CSS styles and then apply these result styles to whatever HTML target you need. E.g. using javascript:

```
var parser = new(less.Parser)(options);
parser.parse(less_src_string, function (err, tree) {
    var css_result_string;
    if (err) {
        // handle errors
    } else {
        css_result_string = tree.toCSS(env);
    }

    // ...
});
```

I'm not aware of any good examples/demos of such in-browser LESS usage so I'm afraid the [less.js](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.5.1.js) and [lessc](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc) sources themselves are the only documentation for this stuff.

#### #2

The other way around is to do it in reverse, i.e. instead of including "less.js" into the frame where you set your variables, include it into your target frame and then set your config frame script to use modifyVars() of the less object defined in the target frame. That  could be much more simple than #1.